# Azure Terraform Error: creating/updating App Service Managed Certificate

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-appservice, azure-rm

I am trying to create a custom certificate binding for a custom certificate for an Azure linux app. The Terraform looked something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding" "myservice_example_com" {
  hostname            = "myservice.example.com"
  app_service_name    = azurerm_linux_web_app.myservice_web_app.name
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_managed_certificate" "myservice_example_com" {
  custom_hostname_binding_id = azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.myservice_example_com.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate_binding" "myservice_example_com" {
  hostname_binding_id = azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.myservice_example_com.id
  certificate_id      = azurerm_app_service_managed_certificate.myservice_example_com.id
  ssl_state           = "SniEnabled"
}
```

Unfortuantely, when running `terraform apply` I received an error:

```
azurerm_app_service_managed_certificate.myservice_example_com: Creating...
│ Error: creating/updating App Service Managed Certificate "myservice.example.com" (Resource Group "rg-myservice"): web.CertificatesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>
```

I had previously created the binding manually, which had succeeded, but I had deleted it before attemping to apply through Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out deleting the binding was not sufficient to delete the certificate that Azure had automatically generated. This was also not easily found by searching in the portal.

I found and deleted the certificate using the CLI:

```
az webapp config ssl list -g rg-myservice
az webapp config ssl delete -g rg-myservice --certificate-thumbprint <REDACTED>
```

Only after doing this I discovered it was possible to access through the portal from the web app's tab:

[image: Azure portal with "Certificates" tab highlighted in the menu]

*Posting to help anyone who runs into the same error message in future.*